# MMS (send & recieve) stopped working last month on Moto X

Tags: mms, moto-x

I'm trying to debug an issue with my wife's Moto X: 
**she sends/receives SMS (individual texts) just fine, but MMS (photos & group texts) fail to send or receive.**

Details

- Moto X (v1) running 4.4.4
- Used to work, and stopped sometime in November
- I've tried switching from Messaging to Messenger to see if it was related to the client app and it made no difference, so I assume the problem is

Any ideas for what to try next? Have you heard of this before? I Googled a bit but couldn't find something quite like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aha!

I just saw the answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/text-message-with-pictures-download-button-does-nothing) and it turns out to be the same thing. Somehow she (or our daughter) turned off her Mobile Data. Turning it on fixed the problem!